# How to groupBy with compiled lambda function with type generated during runtime

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a compiledLambda function that runs against an interface. Unfortunately the interface is just a marker interface and the real type is generated on the fly during runtime and has properties I want to do a grouping on.

Here's some sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Just an example assignment: In the real life scenario the dynamic generated class is created during runtime. 
        IEnumerable<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass> list = GetDataFromService();

        // get the 'real' type from the list
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(list.First().GetType(), typeof(object), "SomeProperty");
        Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object> compiledLambdaFunction = (Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object>)lambdaExpression.Compile();

        // Expected result: Group list on "SomeProp"
        var result = list.GroupBy(compiledLambdaFunction);
    }

    private static IList<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass> GetDataFromService()
    {
        return new List<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass> {  
            new DynamicGeneratedModelClass("Class1"),
            new DynamicGeneratedModelClass("Class2")
        };
    }
}

public interface IDynamicGeneratedModelClass
{}

public class DynamicGeneratedModelClass : IDynamicGeneratedModelClass
{
    public DynamicGeneratedModelClass(string someProperty)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; }
}
```

When the the lambda expression is compiled it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Func`2[ConsoleApp12.DynamicGeneratedModelClass,System.Object]'
>   to type
>   'System.Func`2[ConsoleApp12.IDynamicGeneratedModelClass,System.Object]'.'

Could you please give me a hint what I am doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first generic parameter of the `Func<T, TResult>` delegate is declared as [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) (`in`), which means that you can assign delegate with less derived parameter to delegate with more derived parameter, but not vice versa (in another words, you can cast `Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass,Object>` to `Func<DynamicGeneratedModelClass,Object>`, but cannot cast `Func<DynamicGeneratedModelClass,Object>` to `Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass,Object>`).

To avoid this problem, instead of lambda expression you generate now:

```
// lambda has "wrong" type Func<DynamicGeneratedModelClass, object>
(DynamicGeneratedModelClass item) => item.SomeProperty
```

generate lambda equivalent to this:

```
// lambda now has "correct" type Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object>
(IDynamicGeneratedModelClass item) => ((DynamicGeneratedModelClass)item).SomeProperty
```

I'm not familiar with the `DynamicExpression` library you used to generate you lambda, but this can be easily done using just `System.Linq.Expression` classes:

```
var itemType = list.First().GetType();
var propertyName = "SomeProperty";
var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDynamicGeneratedModelClass));
var castExpr = Expression.Convert(parameterExpr, itemType);
var propExpr = Expression.Property(castExpr, propertyName);
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(propExpr, parameterExpr);

// Compiled lambda is now of type Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object>
Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object> compiledLambdaFunction = (Func<IDynamicGeneratedModelClass, object>)lambdaExpr.Compile();

var result = list.GroupBy(compiledLambdaFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation and your code snippet. 

Your Solution works like a charm, i just had to add a conversion to object, in order to make it work when "SomeProperty" is anything else than string or object.

            var castExprOut = Expression.Convert(propExpr, typeof(object));
            var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(castExprOut, parameterExpr);

Thanks again !